# Cannot allocate vector on a 33k row table merge table

Tags: r, merge, allocation

I'm trying to merge the demographics table ("df_zip_demographics") from the `choroplethrZip` library with another table including with information by Zip codes.

The table I'm trying to add to the "df_zip_demographics" is a simple two column table, "Stores", where the columns are "ZipCode" and "Hit".
When I run this:

```
demo = df_zip_demographics
foo=merge(Stores, demo[ ,c("region")])
```

I get

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.9 Gb

This is a 33k row operation so I find it very odd. What is the problem here?

Comment: Merging may require construction of N^2 sized data-objects.

Comment: Please, post the output of `dput(head(Stores,3))`
and `dput(head(demo,3))` just to have an idea of the data.frame structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the zip code information is in column ZipCode for table Stores and in region for table demo, what you need is

```
foo=merge(Stores, demo, by.x = 'ZipCode', by.y = 'region')
```

Hope it helps